# SQL Server HTML email with variable

Tags: html, sql-server, local-variables

I want to sent a birthday email to my employees and customers.

The email is an HTML email, an before the html content is generating, I set up some variables like salutation, name and contact person, pictures of contact persons will also be generated.... everything works fine, every variables will be filled and shown correctly in the email, but the main email, the content does not work with variable... I tried different variables...

My content is build like:

```
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table class="col--1" style="background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0 auto; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; padding: 0; width: 700px;" width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
              <table class="col--1" style="margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; padding: 0; width: 700px;" width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table class="col--1" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; width: 700px;" width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="col--1" width="700" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Open Sans, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.39; padding: 15px; width: 700px;">
                          <p>
                            '+@SALUTATION+' HAPPY BIRTHDAY
                          </p>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

But that do not work, the same syntax I am using in he header and footer, but there the variables works fine. If I use it without variable in the content, the text is sown, with variable, there is no error, but nothing is shown in the content, only header and footer.

What is my mistake?

Thanks!

*update*
I send emails like that:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
--@recipients = @EMAILMA, 
@recipients = @copy,
--@copy_recipients = @copy,
--@blind_copy_recipients = @copy,
@profile_name = 'SERVER2',
@subject = @sub,
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

Comment: What fails? How did you try to send the email? If you use string concatenation to construct an "HTML" string consider what will happen if one of the fields contains the value `'; Drop Table Users;--`. SQL Server's email functionality is *not* meant to send emails to users. It's meant to send alerts to administrators or rudimentary query results to some users. Creating and emailing nicely formatted reports is the job of SSRS or a custom application

Comment: the text in <p> </p> will not shown in the content in the email, if a variable is in there... without a variable, the <p></p> is shown... or if I have two <p> @Salutation !</p> <p>Happy Birthday to you!</p> the first line is not shown, but Happy Birtday to you! I update my post with the body I will send emails...Should I send emails with php instead of mssql?